# Android Studio: Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Взял курс от Coursera по разработке для андроида, в первом же проекте столкнулся с проблемой. Скачал [отсюда](https://github.com/aporter/coursera-android/tree/master/Examples) TheAnswer проект, попробовал его импортировать и импорта Gradle не разрешил сделать это - выбило такую ошибку:

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
13:10:59.705 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
13:11:00.270 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.server.DaemonServices - Creating daemon context with opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]
13:11:00.333 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] start() called on daemon - DefaultDaemonContext[uid=fbfdb6ee-d530-4190-b211-a2e4fb725aa4,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\vadims.leonovs\.gradle\daemon,pid=6892,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
13:11:00.342 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] updating lastActivityAt to 1438078260342
13:11:00.426 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Software Loopback Interface 1
13:11:00.429 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? true
13:11:00.430 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.431 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
13:11:00.431 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
13:11:00.433 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Software Loopback Interface 1
13:11:00.433 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (SSTP)
13:11:00.435 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.437 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.438 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (SSTP)
13:11:00.438 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (L2TP)
13:11:00.441 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.443 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.443 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (L2TP)
13:11:00.444 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (PPTP)
13:11:00.446 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.449 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.449 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (PPTP)
13:11:00.450 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
13:11:00.451 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.453 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.454 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
13:11:00.454 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)
13:11:00.456 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.458 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.458 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)
13:11:00.459 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
13:11:00.461 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.463 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.463 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
13:11:00.464 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IP)
13:11:00.466 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.468 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.468 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IP)
13:11:00.469 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface RAS Async Adapter
13:11:00.471 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.473 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.474 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface RAS Async Adapter
13:11:00.475 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
13:11:00.477 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.479 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.479 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
13:11:00.480 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
13:11:00.482 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.484 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
13:11:00.484 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:e0:0:0:0%11
13:11:00.485 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
13:11:00.486 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.488 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.489 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /10.122.146.212
13:11:00.489 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:ace3:ed34:9609:491e%12
13:11:00.490 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote multicast interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
13:11:00.490 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
13:11:00.492 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.493 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
13:11:00.494 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:a7a:92d4%13
13:11:00.494 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
13:11:00.496 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.498 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.498 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:8c2f:22a5:c0df:1020%14
13:11:00.499 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
13:11:00.499 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
13:11:00.501 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
13:11:00.503 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
13:11:00.506 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.508 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.509 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:6543:15e3:4281:5e96%16
13:11:00.509 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding remote multicast interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
13:11:00.510 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
13:11:00.512 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.514 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? false
13:11:00.515 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.517 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.520 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.520 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.521 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.523 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.525 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.525 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.526 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.527 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.529 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.530 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.532 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.534 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.534 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.535 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Virtual WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.536 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.539 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Virtual WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.539 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.542 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.543 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.543 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.547 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.547 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.547 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.549 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.551 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.551 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.552 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.553 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.558 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.560 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.560 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.562 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.564 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.564 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.565 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.567 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.569 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.569 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.570 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IP)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.571 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.573 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.573 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IP)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.574 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.575 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.577 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.578 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.578 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.580 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.582 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.583 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.583 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.585 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.587 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.587 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.588 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.589 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.591 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.592 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.592 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.594 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.596 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.596 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface DW1530 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.597 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.598 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.600 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.601 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-Native WiFi Filter Driver-0000
13:11:00.601 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.603 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.605 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.605 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000
13:11:00.606 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.607 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.609 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.610 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-WFP LightWeight Filter-0000
13:11:00.610 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.612 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
13:11:00.614 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
13:11:00.615 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter-Symantec Endpoint Protection Firewall-0000
13:11:00.619 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.TcpIncomingConnector] Listening on [2dd41106-28f8-4395-bab9-a4ab260bd7ee port:63691, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]].
13:11:00.629 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] Daemon starting at: Tue Jul 28 13:11:00 EEST 2015, with address: [2dd41106-28f8-4395-bab9-a4ab260bd7ee port:63691, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]]
13:11:00.630 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DomainRegistryUpdater] Advertising the daemon address to the clients: [2dd41106-28f8-4395-bab9-a4ab260bd7ee port:63691, addresses:[/127.0.0.1, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]]
13:11:00.631 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DomainRegistryUpdater] Advertised daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=fbfdb6ee-d530-4190-b211-a2e4fb725aa4,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\vadims.leonovs\.gradle\daemon,pid=6892,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
13:11:00.632 [DEBUG]
```

Это впринципе не весь лог, этот портал не позволяет мне добавить весь, но если будет не достаточно я придумаю как добавить оставшейся кусок ошибки. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел решение:

1. Удалить папку workspace.
2. Заново импортировать проект.
3. Создать новую папку workspace.
4. Gradle предложит установить sdk, установить это (Я не знаю почему он предполагает?)
5. Работает!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вы открыли слишком много приложений в вашей ОС либо вашей машине не хватает **оперативной памяти**. В связи с этим студия просто напросто не может запустить daemon process. Ознакомьтесь с системными требованиями AS для вашей ОС. Ещё попробуйте вот это File Menu - > Invalidate Caches/ Restart->Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: Не помогло. Насчет оперативно памяти, после запуска AS у меня еще свободно 3.5 гб, думаю хватит, ведь другие проекты я могу запустить, только с этим проблема.